# How can I make PowerShell get environmental variables on Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: bash, powershell, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.10

I have installed PowerShell on Ubuntu 20.10 and I'm trying to use it on terminal but it does not seem to know the environmental variables. How can I make PowerShell know the environmental variables on Ubuntu?

Comment: That's like trying to run a python program with a javascript interpreter and expecting it to work...

Comment: @Shawn OK, understood. How can PowerShell get environmental variables on Ubuntu?

Comment: bash -c env?...

Comment: Powershell does support Linux. It *does* have quirks, but the basic support is there.

Answer (score 0):

`Write-Host $Env:PATH` is an example of how to access an environment variable from Powershell in Linux. Note: the variable names are case sensitive.

If you want to see the variables that Powershell can "see",

`Get-ChildItem Env:` - this gets variables that are exported to the enviroment. It will not get variables that are *local* to the session.

If you run `printenv` from Ubuntu, you'll see all of the variables exported to the enviroment - these will be available to Powershell as indicated above.

If you run `set` from Ubuntu, you'll see all variables (enviromnent and shell variables). To make it available from Powershell, you will need to export it:

```sh
export x=$someshellvariable
pwsh
PS /mnt/c/git> Get-ChildItem $Env:x

Name                           Value
----                           -----
x                              test
```

Comment: I've tried it and it give very few paths compared to what I know there is. I wonder where does PowerShell read these or how can I make it know what bash knows.

Comment: Updated answer - there's more behind variables and how they are supported in Powershell that should be taken into account.